# bootstrap make accordion responsive?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the Bootstrap 3 Accordion Collapse,right now everything loads in one column, how can I make it so the panels use multiple columns in desktop resolution and one column in mobile mode?

```
        <div class="row">

            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

                <?php
                foreach ($states as &$state) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#<?php echo $state; ?>">
                                    <?php echo $state; ?></a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="<?php echo $state; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                            <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                                sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
                                minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                                commodo consequat.</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php }
                ?>
            </div>

        </div>
```

EDIT

This is my edided html

```
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">

                    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

                        <?php
                        foreach ($states as &$state) {
                            ?>
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#<?php echo preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $state); ?>">
                                            <?php echo $state; ?></a>
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                                <div id="<?php echo preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $state); ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                    <div class="panel-body">test</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php }
                        ?>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

and it looks like this now. Only one slim column in desktop resolution

[image]

Comment: Every `.row` should contain a `.col-`. If you always apply a `.col-xs-` class then you will always have a responsive container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your amended code wont work simply because you are defining the `col` before the `foreach` so you are wrapping all of them into one `col`. You should have the `col` inside your `foreach` so they all wrap independently.

Try this:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($states as &$state) { ?>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#<?php echo $state; ?>">
                            <?php echo $state; ?></a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="<?php echo $state; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
                        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                        commodo consequat.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- col-md-4 now closes here -->
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Also it is bad practise within Bootstrap to have a `div` inbetween your `row` and `cols`

Hopefully this works for you!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is what you mean, but wouldn't it be enough to wrap your accordion in a col- class?

Like:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

            <?php
            foreach ($states as &$state) {
                ?>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#<?php echo $state; ?>">
                                <?php echo $state; ?></a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="<?php echo $state; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
                            minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                            commodo consequat.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php }
            ?>
        </div>
   </div><!-- colse col-md-4 -->
    </div>
```

Comment: I wrapped it, but it's only one column in desktop mode. I edited my question and added an image of what it looks like

Answer (score 0):

if this is your answer:

all you have to do is add bootstrap column classes before the panel group.

> col-xs-12  smaller screen sizes, col-md-4 medium screen sizes / PC,
>   col-lg-12 for large screen sizes, col-sm-6 for tablet screen sizes.

Comment: I wrapped it, but it's only one column in desktop mode. I edited my question and added an image of what it looks like